# How to generate Hibernate mapping files from Database

Tags: hibernate, annotations, code-generation

I have both a schema that served in the creation of my database, as well as the database itself.

I'm wondering if there exists any tool that can create a Hibernate mapping for the entities specified in the schema.

My preference would be for the tool to generate Object files with annotations, but if that is impossible, then I will have to accept XML annotations.

I am aware of `Hibernate Code Generation` that is part of JBoss tools, but I haven't been able to configure it to generate annotations.

Does anyone have any advice on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "Hibernate Code Generation", do you mean the [reverse engineering tool](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.1.0.Beta1/hibernatetools/html/reverseengineering.html)? That's the only thing I know of for generating things from a database schema for Hibernate. I don't think there's a single-step solution to go from schema to annotated classes, but if you use the reverse engineering tool to generate XML mapping files, you could then use the [POJO exporter](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.1.0.Beta1/hibernatetools/html/ant.html#d0e2903) to generate annotated classes from the XML.